# browserify: bundle library and extend it afterwards

Tags: javascript, build, bundle, browserify, require

I'm working on a library using browserify. I have an entry point e.js which requires the files a.js b.js c.js.

As long as i'm just bundling the complete library,
`browserify -e e.js -o dist/lib.js` works just fine.

However, I'd like the library to be extensible by others. They should be able to load `lib.js` in their code and then `require('./c.js')`from the library.

Using `factor-bundle` it will always create a new `dist/lib.js`which is incompatible with the originally built one.

I guess using `browserify -r` with all internal dependencies to build `dist/lib.js`and then doing a `browserify -x ... -e module.js -o dist/module.js`, externalizing all library dependencies will work, but isn't there an automated way of achieving this?

Is it possible to create a bundle with all dependencies being exported and then creating a second bundle for the add-on module which automatically externalizes everything from the first bundle?

Thanks for your answers!